# Is there a command-line BitTorrent client preinstalled on OS X?

Tags: macos, command-line, torrent

On a "bare" [OS X 10.8 install](http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/osx-ci-environment/), what is the easiest way to grab a largish torrent from the command line ([MacTeX](http://tug.org/mactex/), 2.3 GB)? I can't use GUI-only clients, it's a headless system. If no such client is preinstalled, which one would be easiest to install and get running?

**EDIT**: To be more specific, I'm looking for a command similar to `wget` or `curl` that would get a torrent and serve only this torrent while running, then exiting when the download is complete.

Comment: `curl -O http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/mac/mactex/MacTeX.pkg` would work as well

Comment: @patrix: [Too slow](https://travis-ci.org/krlmlr/r-travis/jobs/13435831).

Comment: Based on your edit, added info about aria2 which offers simple .torrent or magnet downloads: `aria2c http://example.org/mylinux.torrent`

Comment: @grgarside: Thank you. Looks like the best option for me, too -- I can even install from homebrew. Let's see...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No, not pre-installed as far as I know.

---

Try **[Deluge](http://deluge-torrent.org)**.

> It has been designed using the client server model with a daemon process that handles all the bittorrent activity. The Deluge daemon is able to run on headless machines with the user-interfaces being able to connect remotely from any platform.

<sup>Source: [About Deluge](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/About)</sup>

Alternatively, try [rTorrent](http://libtorrent.rakshasa.no), **[aria2](http://aria2.sourceforge.net)**, or [TorrentFlux](http://sourceforge.net/projects/torrentflux/).

For simple downloading of .torrent or magnet torrents, aria2 might be your best option.

---

*Setting up aria2:*

1. Install aria2 per the [official install instructions](https://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/aria2/wiki/Download).
2. aria2 can accept .torrent links and magnet links:

   ```
   aria2c http://example.org/mylinux.torrent
   aria2c 'magnet:?xt=urn:btih:248D0A1CD08284299DE78D5C1ED359BB46717D8C'
   ```

---

*Setting up Deluge console access:*

1. Install Deluge per the [official install instructions](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/Installing).
2. Run the daemon and the console process, then connect locally.

   ```
   deluged
   deluge-console
   connect 127.0.0.1:{{DELUGEDPORT}}
   ```
3. Add a torrent per this syntax:

   ```
   add [-p <save-location>] <torrent-file> [<torrent-file> ...]
   ```
4. Use `--help` flag for more help on commands.

*Setting up Deluge remote access:*

1. Install Deluge per the [official install instructions](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/Installing).
2. Create the configuration files by starting/stopping the daemon:

   ```
   deluged
   pill deluged
   ```
3. Add authentication with the syntax `<username>:<password>:<level>`:

   ```
   echo "alice:MyC0mpL3xPass:10" >> ~/.config/deluge/auth
   ```

   <sup>[About authentication levels](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/Authentication)</sup>
4. Allow connections beyond `localhost`.

   ```
   deluge-console "config -s allow_remote True"
   deluge-console "config allow_remote"
   ```
5. Start the daemon.

   ```
   deluged
   ```

*Setting up rTorrent:*

1. Install rTorrent per the official [download](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/Authentication) & [install](http://libtorrent.rakshasa.no/wiki/Install) instructions.
2. Run `rtorrent` to begin the interactive access.

   Use `-h` flag for more info on using rTorrent.

Comment: Could you please give a usage example on how to install these and start downloading a given torrent, from the command line?

Comment: @krlmlr Added some info :)

Comment: the link is broken https://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/aria2/wiki/Download

Comment: @Mona Thanks for the comment, I've edited the post, you are welcome to make edits like that yourself!